# OUTPUT Clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to simulate the OUTPUT clause in MySQL, as we have a OUTPUT clause in SQL Server.

Here is the kind of query I have

```
UPDATE       employee
SET          empage = 10
OUTPUT       INSERTED.empid
WHERE        (empage < 10)
```

As I need to have this functionality for MySQL server database too.

Kindly suggest the best way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. You could create a trigger and insert values you need into another table.
2. I'm not sure, but - for MYISAM tables you could lock `employee` table, select and insert values into another table, and then update and unlock `employee` table.

**EDIT:**

I have tried one scenario with InnoDb table, seems it works -

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE; -- lock rows
-- Or call this select to insert and lock rows
-- INSERT INTO table_output SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;

-- Make modifications
UPDATE table SET column1 = '111' WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT;
```

[SELECT statement (FOR UPDATE clause)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Comment: I thought of having some clauses in the query that did this trick.. anyways.. let me check the possibilities

Comment: i am using InnoDB and donot want to create a trigger, as this needs control from my app. Is there a lock mechanism that i can use?

Comment: I have this query being answered in http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/query-regarding-combining-an-update-and-an-insert-query-into-a-single-query-in-my/3557. For your reference.