# MySQL: Get a return result from an INSERT SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have query that INSERTS both explicit values and SELECTd content. I'm also doing basic incrementing.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`myID`, `myVal1`, `myVal2`) SELECT `myID` + 1, 'explValHere', 'otherValThere')
FROM `table` ORDER BY `myID` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

I am doing this as the table has multiple id's and incrementing within a specific column. So I can't, as you would first say, use auto incrementing and insert_id.

The problem of course is the insert doesn't return the select, but can it? Is there a way of running this insert query and returning any of the result?

Comment: SQL Server has an `OUTPUT` clause that suits this problem perfectly. There's a discussion about emulating that over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817414/output-clause-in-mysql).

Comment: Interesting @ta.speot.is - Shame :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query has a `LIMIT 1` you could store the "result" in a [session/user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Still two queries but reentrant; each connection is its own session.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

$query = "
    INSERT INTO tbl1 (myID, myVal1, myVal2)
    SELECT @foo:=myID+1, 'val1', 'val2' FROM tbl2 WHERE x=0 LIMIT 1
";
$pdo->exec($query);
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT @foo as foo') as $row ) {
    echo $row['foo'];
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl1 (myID int, myVal1 varchar(16), myVal2 varchar(16))');
    $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl2 (myID int, x int)');
    $pdo->exec('INSERT INTO tbl2 (myID, x) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,0),(4,0),(5,1)');
}
```

the "first" record in tbl2 having x=0 is (myID=3,x=0) and the script prints `4`.

Other than that and stored procedures et al there's (to my knowledge) nothing like SQLServer's [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177564.aspx) or postgresql's [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-insert.html) clause for MySQL.

Comment: SQL language is by definition orderless with table and or resultsets, using `LIMIT` to match the "first" matching  record without `ORDER BY` is pretty much meaningless.. Pagination or batching in SQL language requires a deterministic `ORDER BY` to be used meaning there needs to be atleast one column in the `ORDER BY` clause which has a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key..

Comment: So `INSERT INTO tbl1 (myID, myVal1, myVal2) SELECT @foo:=myID+1, 'val1', 'val2' FROM tbl2 WHERE x=0 LIMIT 1` should have been `INSERT INTO tbl1 (myID, myVal1, myVal2) SELECT @foo:=myID+1, 'val1', 'val2' FROM tbl2 WHERE x=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` assuming id column which has a `PRIMARY KEY`..

Answer (score 0):

You can (in a transaction) first read the values and afterwards do your insert statement.

Comment: The behaviour highly depends on the transaction isolation level. Choose the wrong level, and you have a nice race condition.

Comment: @waxical Yes. I added transaction requirement just to be sure, that no other select/insert comes in between. If you are the only user that's not necessary, of course.

Comment: assuming innoDB engine and using  `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` before running the topicstarters query should be fine as that should stop phantom reads in the batch -> `ORDER BY myID DESC LIMIT 0,1`, which @0xCAFEBABE i assume means with his comment -> *"The behaviour highly depends on the transaction isolation level. Choose the wrong level, and you have a nice race condition. "*

Comment: be aware as  it dont fully know for sure how `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` is implemented in MySQL a whole table lock might be created for the topicstarters query as there is no limiting `WHERE` range so all table records could match the `SELECT` ...

Answer (score 0):

try like this after your normal insert

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`myID`, `myVal1`, `myVal2`) values ('xxx','xxxx','xxxx');
```

then execute the queryget last inser id using

```
$id=mysql_insert_id();
```

then update the inserted row as below

```
mysql_query("update table set myid=$id where id=$id");
```

Comment: if you want inserted values in return write a query to fetch records inserted lastly using same id

Comment: This relies on having a generated id using auto increment, which I state is not being used on this field. Unless you mean to use an auto-incrementing id to link the two. That's awfully messy with another update.