# Return Select Query Of Insert Statement MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this simple query

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO NewCourses (name, location, gid) from
SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses
```

which does nothing but insert all records from table **courses** to table **NewCourses** .

But if I would like to return this same select statement what will I do?
Without this I need to run this insert statement then again run the same select statement like

```
INSERT INTO NewCourses (name, location, gid) from
SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses

//THIS IS THE WASTE OF TIME
SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses
```

Please let me know if it is possible?

Comment: Your method is fine.  `INSERT` statements don't return results.  `SELECT` statements don't modify the database.  That is how SQL is designed.

Comment: ok then wont it be wastage? especially if select query takes too long?

Comment: *"ok then wont it be wastage? especially if select query takes too long? "* Sounds like you want to switch to PostgreSQL... `INSERT INTO NewCourses ... RETURING name, location, 1` ..  Anyhow also don't expect it do be fast there if `SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses` needs to copy great data sizes also in PostgreSQL it is also meant as syntax sugar that you don't have to write a separate SELECT..

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI . . . Really, you should select the values from `NewCourses`.  Perhaps you want to save the results in a *temporary* table, insert the temporary table into `NewCourses` and then select from that.  If the query is complicated, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: Maybe it depends on datatypes and if MySQL can handle that temporary table in memory (settings wise)..   @GordonLinoff .. otherwise it will be more wastefull then the topicstarters queries with Disk I/O as the temporary table needs to be converted from ram to disk..

Comment: [MySQL: Get a return result from an INSERT SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067121/mysql-get-a-return-result-from-an-insert-select)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479315/sql-inserting-a-row-and-returning-primary-key

Comment: If you really want to save a roundtrip, you can wrap that two queries into a stored procedure and call that SP in your code

Comment: I am already calling it from SP

Comment: *"If you really want to save a roundtrip, you can wrap that two queries into a stored procedure and call that SP in your code "*@PeterHe the stored procedure in this case  would most likely be equal or use more overhead then running a separared `INSERT / SELECT` as  a  stored procedure  statements use up more memory and most likely needs the used memory longer before the resources are freed on the MySQL server... Using a stored procedure in this case is not really justifiable in my opinion ...