# sql: how can I find a value and replace it simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do something like that

```
SELECT * WHERE owner = '81',

    owner = NULL

FROM outcome
```

or

```
UPDATE outcome SET NULL WHERE owner = '81'
```

So before request the table contains values `81` but after request corresponding values in NULL.

Comment: `UPDATE outcome SET owner = NULL WHERE owner = '81'` does exactly that. Is it something else you're looking for? Like a recordset of updated rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming outcome is your table name, here is what you need:

```
UPDATE outcome 
SET owner = NULL 
WHERE owner = '81'
```

If you also want to select the updated rows see here:

[OUTPUT Clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817414/output-clause-in-mysql)

So... in MySQL that part seems a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM OUTCOME WHERE (OWNER IS NULL OR OWNER='81')

UPDATE outcome SET owner=NULL 
WHERE owner = '81'
```