# Why am I getting errors with OUTPUT clause here?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return an identity column `passid` after inserting a few values into a table. `passid` is an autoincrement column. I'm using the OUTPUT clause to get it done.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `PASSENGERS`(`passname`, `passdob`, `passgen`, `passadd`, `passproof`, `passmobile`, `passemail`, `flight_no`, `org`, `dest`, `bookingemail`, `dot`) VALUES ('$passname1','$passdob1','$passgen1','$passadd1','$passproof1','$passmobile1','$passemail1','$flight_no','$origin','$destination','$bookingemail','$dateoftravel') OUTPUT INSERTED.passid VALUES('$passname1','$passdob1','$passgen1','$passadd1','$passproof1','$passmobile1','$passemail1','$flight_no','$origin','$destination','$bookingemail','$dateoftravel');";
```

If I execute this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `PASSENGERS`(`passname`, `passdob`, `passgen`, `passadd`, `passproof`, `passmobile`, `passemail`, `flight_no`, `org`, `dest`, `bookingemail`, `dot`) VALUES ('ABC','2019-11-30','Male','DFA','Aadhar Card','1234567890','ABC@gmail.com','SB1123','Bengaluru','Hyderabad','mkchaaru@yahoo.com','2019-11-15') OUTPUT INSERTED.passid VALUES('ABC','2019-11-30','Male','DFA','Aadhar Card','1234567890','ABC@gmail.com','SB1123','Bengaluru','Hyderabad','mkchaaru@yahoo.com','2019-11-15');
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Unexpected token. (near "OUTPUT" at position 312)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "OUTPUT" at position 312)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "INSERTED" at position 319)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "passid" at position 328)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "VALUES" at position 335)
```

My table structure

[image]

Comment: OUTPUT is not supported in mysql. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817414/output-clause-in-mysql

Comment: What would be the best alternative for OUTPUT in mysql then?

Comment: use this `select last_insert_id()`

Comment: what are you going passid? you can ignore entire line if you are not doing anything after insert